# Why is MySQL suddenly getting a lot of queries in a "Waiting for table flush" state? How can this be fixed?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Recently my database started, several times a day, to get stuck with a lot of queries in a `Waiting for table flush` state.
Usually there's a very long query in execution that when killed unlock the other queries.
We don't execute automatically `ANALYZE`, `OPTIMIZE`, `RENAME`, `ALTER`, `REPAIR` and `FLUSH` commands that could cause a flush.

The tables are all InnoDB and the version of MySQL is `5.7.39-1`.

There are hundreds of client connected all of the time (372 at the time I'm writing this question).

The database is managed, so I don't have the `PROCESS` privilege required to execute the query

```sql
SELECT BLOCKING_TRX_ID FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_LOCK_WAITS;
```

that could be used to further debug the issue.

Can you help me to debug this issue?

Comment: "Managed"?  That probably includes periodic backups.  What is the schedule for such?  If that does not lead to an answer, get them do provide PROCESSLIST and SHOW ENGINE=INNODB STATUS.

Comment: @RickJames The backups are executed daily in the morning, and to my knowlege should require under a day to execute, and the queries get stuck even in the evening. I'll try to get confirmations of this from our hosting company, thanks.

Comment: If your database is "managed", then whoever "manages" it should take care of the problem. If they won't, you should stop paying for such "service" and either find a properly managed DBaaS, or manage it yourself.

Comment: I agree with @mustaccio. Processlist is required for further analysis.

Comment: Possibly related feature request: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87065 I know you said you don't run ANALYZE TABLE, but this could be a case when similar work is being done automatically by periodic statistics refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further debugging the issue with the provider, as suggested by @RickJames , I found out that they executed an hourly cron that analyzed every table and was the cause of the flushes.

I wasn't able to view this queries in the PROCESSLIST because they were executed with an administrative account.

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: It sounds like you need to switch to a competent managed database service provider. :-( Your experience is, unfortunately, far from unique.